# Make child flex measure the same height and width different row

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have 4 items inside a flex container. I want to make the 4 of them the same width and height, but always having them in 2 different rows (so a 2 X 2 grid).

Since the children are in different flex containers, they do not obey  `flex-grow: 1;` Even the children of the same row do not obey the rule. And if I put them in the same container, they put themselves in the same row, and I need the 2 X 2 grid.

You can find a codepen here with the same code: https://codepen.io/mongolhippie/pen/yLYQbVd?editors=1100

```css
    .tile {
      display: flex;
    
      flex-direction: column;
      border: 2px solid #A97C50;
      border-radius: 20px;
      padding: 20px;
      margin: 25px;
      /* THESE 3 OPTIONS TO CONTROLL HAVING THE SAME SPACE FOR EVERY TILE */
      flex-grow: 1;
      flex-shrink: 1;
      flex-basis: 0;
      flex: 1;
    }
    
    .tile p {
      font-size: min(calc( 1.125vw + 1.2rem ), 3.9rem);
    }
    .flex-center{
        display: flex !important;
        justify-content: center !important;
        align-items: center;
    }
    
    .manual-link {
      text-decoration: none !important;
      color: var(--brown-dark);
    }
    
    .manual-link:hover {
      text-decoration: none !important;
      color: var(--brown-dark);
    }
    
    .icon-and-title{  
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
    }
    
    .icon-and-title p{
      font-size: min(calc( 1.125vw + .9rem ), 3.9rem);
    }
    
    .icon-and-title img{
      max-width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      transition: all .3s;
      max-height: 80px;
      margin-right: 20px;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
```

```html
     <div class="flex-center">
          <a class="manual-link" href="/manuals/manual-it.pdf">
          <div class="tile">
            <div class="icon-and-title">
              <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/06/bc/e8/06bce81285badba0c3becd273ca67f95.png" alt="">
              <p>ADMIN</p>
            </div>
            <div class="links-manuals">
              <p>For the administrator of the app</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          </a>
          <a class="manual-link" href="/manuals/manual-developers.pdf">
          <div class="tile">
            <div class="icon-and-title">
              <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/06/bc/e8/06bce81285badba0c3becd273ca67f95.png" alt="">
              <p>DEVELOPERS</p>
            </div>
            <div class="links-manuals">
              <p>To upgrade the Code</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          </a>
    
    
        </div>
        <div class="flex-center">
          <a class="manual-link" href="/manuals/manual-design.pdf">
          <div class="tile">
            <div class="icon-and-title">
              <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/06/bc/e8/06bce81285badba0c3becd273ca67f95.png" alt="">
              <p>DESIGNERS</p>
            </div>
            <div class="links-manuals">
              <p>Style guide</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          </a>
          <a class="manual-link" href="/manuals/ngo.pdf">
          <div class="tile">
            <div class="icon-and-title">
              <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/06/bc/e8/06bce81285badba0c3becd273ca67f95.png" alt="">
              <p>NGOs</p>
            </div>
            <div class="links-manuals">
              <p>The project</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          </a>
        </div>
```

Which is the secret to having them in a 2 X 2 disposition with the same width and height??

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply move from Flexbox to CSS GRID.

So change the CSS like this:

```
.flex-center{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}
```

Since you are handling your layout in 2 different rows we'll play with the `grid-template-columns`.

The `fr` unit tells the grid to have to "cells" with the same width.

Better renaming the class from `.flex-center` to something else since you'll use CSS GRID.

Here the updated working [Codepen](https://codepen.io/alezuc/pen/RwWqVQM?editors=1100)

Answer (score 1):

Flebox are very good to make a 1D flexible container (vertically or horizontally) and can also handle multi-lines when they is no more space for all elements (instead of overflow the container)

**BUT** They is another display type used mainly for 2D flexible grid. And it's called [grid](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp), you should look at [this guid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) in order to use it right.

As you want by default a 2D (2x2) grid, it'll be way easier to use it, This is a very basic grid you can set in order to have both columns and rows to take half of available space (50%)

```
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
  grid-template-rows: 50% 50%;
}
```